# Why gradle is not available of Maven repo for tnt4j-api-final-all.jar and TNT4j.jar

Tags: maven, jar, maven-plugin

I have downloaded tnt4j-api-final-all.jar and TNT4j.jar and kept in `lib` folder of Grails application. But now requirements has changed I need to give maven central to these two jar. But I found there is no maven so what is best way. How can I upload these plugins to Maven?

Comment: I am not sure if I got question but you know that grail's has each own dependencies management functionality right ? Other than that please consider on improving your question it does not make much sense right now !

Comment: @Nikolis.Py I am looking maven for above two jar which are not available on maven so how can I upload these 2 jars to maven. very simple words hope you understood.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for those artifacts and could not find them on any Maven public repository.

What you need to do is install them on your machine using `maven-install-plugin`:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=path-to-artifact-jar -DgroupId=[groupId] -DartifactId=[artifactId] -Dversion=[version] -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

and then you can use those dependencies with:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>[groupId]</groupId>
    <artifactId>[artifactId]</artifactId>
    <version>[version]</version>
</dependency>
```

Another solution is to use a private repository manager like Artifactory and upload the artifact there.

Comment: Can you tell more about second option. @Tunaki

Comment: @SohamShetty When you need to manage a lot of Maven dependencies, it is often a good idea to have a internal repository: it can store Maven public dependencies by downloading them automatically and caching them and it can also store user-uploaded artifacts that are not available on Maven repo. The advantage is that there is no need to install the artifact on each developer's machine. Take a look at [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/),

Comment: I went through documents where I downloaded artifactory and try to install but installation is not completed. when I browse http://localhost:8081/artifactory giving webpage not available. can you help me if you know. using windows 10 and jdk 8 update 60

Comment: @SohamShetty We are going way out of the scope of the initial question here. I suggest you go with the first option and create a new question for Artifactory if you want to use it.

Comment: but you have given answer for pom.xml we are not using I need gradle.

Comment: Your question is tagged [tag:maven] so I'm answering for that. But it is the same for Gradle except the dependency is declared `compile group: '[groupId]', name: '[artifactId]', version: '[version]'`

Comment: Even if I do this it will not become specific to me what about other in organization and may be anyone one who is using. @Tunaki